# Mercurial - race condition when pushing with subrepos

Tags: mercurial, push, race-condition, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

With a fairly basic subrepo structure like this:

> parent
>   parent/subrepo1
>   parent/subrepo2

Race conditions tend to occur when multiple users push changes at the same time. Simple example:

User 1 & 2 begin pushing.
User 1 skips `parent/subrepo1`, no changes.
User 2 pushes to `parent/subrepo1`, with changes.
User 1 pushes to `parent/subrepo2`, with changes.
User 2 tries to push to `parent/subrepo2`, but cannot because it will create multiple heads.
User 1 finishes pushing `parent`.

The result of this is that User 1 managed to push everything successfully, but User 2 partially pushed and then failed. This left a head on `parent/subrepo1` which doesn't have a corresponding commit in `parent`, which will cause problems for the next person to push `parent/subrepo1` unless User 2 discovers their error, pulls `parent`, merges, commits, and then attempts to push (but there's no guarantee another user won't attempt to push at the same time again!).

My question: Is there a way within Mercurial to force users to wait while a push operation is underway on a Mercurial repository with other subrepos (to effectively implement a mutex) **OR** is there a way to undo a failed push on the target's changed subrepos when a user fails to push.